# Change variable

Tags: c

I have 4 different arrays:

```
array_1[2][2]
array_2[2][2]
array_3[2][2]
array_4[2][2]
```

And now I want to print out the first line of ALL arrays:

```
    int x=0;
    int i=0;
    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
      printf("%c ", array_x[i][j]);
      if (j == 1)
      {
       x++;
       j=0;
      }
    }
```

With the variable x I want to reach array_1 to array_4, but this is not working. What is the syntax for this?

Comment: a set of variable names cannot be selected by the technique your using.  Instead, write (in this case 4) a for loop for each variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what arrays are meant to accomplish.

So instead of having `array_1[2][2]` through 4, you would have one array, possibly something like:

`a[4][2][2]`

and the first element of each would be referenced by `a[x][0][0]`

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use a list of pointers to each of the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You should merge your 4 arrays into a 3D array : array[4][2][2].
That way you'll be able to loop on one particular dimension

Answer (score 0):

```
// use the following code to print out the first line of each array.
// note: 
//     the rowLength definition is so, if later the array row length changes
//     it only has to be updated in one place
// note:
//     the parens around the defined value, this habit can eliminate 
//     several errors when using more complex expressions/macros
#define rowLength (2)

int j = 0;
for ( j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
{
    printf("%c ", array_1[0][j]);
}
for ( j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
{
    printf("%c ", array_2[0][j]);
}
for ( j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
{
    printf("%c ", array_3[0][j]);
}
for ( j = 0; j < rowLength; j++)
{
    printf("%c ", array_4[0][j]);
}
```